# “The compressed (zip) folder is invalid or corrupted” error after downloading zip file Win10

Tags: windows-10, file-transfer, zip

After upgrading a Windows 7 PC to Windows 10, I get “The compressed (zip) folder is invalid or corrupted” error after downloading zip file when using Filezilla to download the file. If I use Windows explorer to FTP to the site, I am able to copy the [zip] file via drag and drop, and it opens just fine. Any suggestions what would cause this?

Comment: In your FileZilla, what is selected under Transfer menu > Transfer type?

Comment: ASCII. I changed it to "Auto" and that seemed to fix it for this particular server. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

Under Transfer [Menu] -> Transfer type, it was set to ASCII. I changed it to "Auto" and that seemed to fix it for this particular server.

Comment: If I recall correctly, ASCII mode implies that the FTP protocol (client-side? server-side?) will "port" the line endings/encoding/storage structure for plain-text files on dissimilar systems. This (obviously) will corrupt most files.

Comment: Thank you!
~John